# php serialize huge float causes rounding and formatting issues

Tags: php

I have the following php snippet

```
$newData = serialize(array('ep' => 50733372961735.4));
echo "New data: " . print_r($newData, 1);
```

Output:

```
New data: a:1:{s:2:"ep";d:5.07333729617E+13;}
```

But I would like the float value as it is and not E+13.

What could I do without having to make drastic changes as this is just an example. In my actual code the 'ep' value could be inside a complex array hierarchy

Comment: Store it as a string if you want it as accurate as you provide it (or use a maths library). PHP only has a finite accuracy when it comes to floats.

Comment: i tried settype - which didnt work as it rounded it down

Comment: `serialize(array('ep' => "50733372961735.4"));` fun fact this is not a problem on all machines. Check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61556f1a7d15a8db54d8cd1c4e9cbd4a4722e450

Comment: You can either raise the precision `ini_set( 'precision', 30 );` or us a string.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a general note: **serialize should never be used on data that could be manipulated in any way**. It's useful for things like session data and caches, but should not be relied on for transporting data between applications or data storage. In many cases, you're better off using a standard serialization format like JSON.

You also certainly shouldn't care what the serialized string *looks like* - the *only* thing you should do with that string is pass it back to `unserialize()`. So the fact that there is `E+13` is not a problem if the actual value it gives back when you unserialize is the one you wanted.

However, it's clear in your example that you have lost precision - the last digits are `...29617` rather than `...29617354` - so back to the point: there is a PHP setting `serialize_precision`, [described in the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.serialize-precision). It's default value has varied over the years, but setting it to an explicit value other than -1 will serialize floats with that number of significant figures:

```
ini_set('serialize_precision', 2);
echo serialize(50733372961735.4), PHP_EOL;
// d:5.1E+13;

ini_set('serialize_precision', 20);
echo serialize(50733372961735.4), PHP_EOL;
// d:50733372961735.398438;
```

Note that the first example has clearly thrown away information, whereas the second has actually stored more precision than you realised you had - because of [the inaccuracy of storing decimals in binary floating point format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the serialize at all!

it's numbers in general.

```
$num = 50733372961735.4;
print($num);

=> 50733372961735
```

to "solve" this problem you can use:

```
ini_set('serialize_precision', 15);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong on both counts: `serialize` *is* explicitly choosing a precision to write the float with, and it is *not* governed by the `precision` setting, but a separate `serialize_precision` setting.

Comment: try it and you will see I'm right. the default (after php 5.4.0 is 17). he needs only 15. so the thing that round it is not the serializer

Comment: What you have posted is true, but *it is not the issue the OP is having*. They are using `serialize`, and having problems with the accuracy of the serialized form, which is unrelated to the accuracy used when printing the number.

Comment: again, you are wrong. the default for serialize_precision is 17. he need only 15. the precision is (by default) less than 15 so it rounds it

Comment: So what rounds it? The output shown in the question is *the result of `serialize`*, so has been rounded only by `serialize`, which obeys `serialize_precision`. The `precision` setting is used only when *displaying* numbers, so is irrelevant to the `serialize` output.

Comment: you are right, i looked at the wrong output. I fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171563/discussion-between-i-v-and-imsop).

Answer (score -1):

I just executed your code on www.writephponline.com

I got the below value if I did not put your value in string :- `$newData = serialize(array('ep' => 50733372961735.4));`

> New data: a:1:{s:2:"ep";d:50733372961735.398;}

and this after adding it in string :- `$newData = serialize(array('ep' => '50733372961735.4'));`

> New data: a:1:{s:2:"ep";s:16:"50733372961735.4";}

Comment: Yes, the precision depends on PHP version and a runtime setting, so different environments will behave differently. That doesn't solve the problem though.